# SpringBoot - file upload bigger than 500kb not working

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, file-upload, spring-webflux

i have SpringBoot (v2.7.1, Spring v5.3.21) project with Kotlin and WebFlux. I'm trying to create a simple file upload controller that works so far, but only for files smaller than 500kb.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/emailFile")
class EmailController {
    val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this::class.java)

    @PostMapping("/upload", consumes = [MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE])
    suspend fun uploadFile(
        @RequestPart("attachment") attachment: FilePart,
        @RequestPart("message") message: String
    ): ResponseEntity<String> {

        val content = attachment.content().awaitFirst()
        val bytes = content.asByteBuffer()

        logger.debug(bytes.array().size.toString())

        File("testfilespring.png").writeBytes(bytes.array());

        return  ResponseEntity(message, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
    }
}
```

When I log `bytes.array().size` for files larger than 500kb it is always 1024. Posting files < 500kb works perfectly.

Uploading files via postman or via react application with fetch method:
[image]

When I go through the application log, I don't see anything in it. I also tried setting the max file size as well, but without success.

```
spring:
  servlet:
    multipart:
      enabled: true
      max-file-size: 10MB
      max-request-size: 10MB
```

Comment: Is it possible that you set the wrong properties? I think servlet is only for non reactive webapps. The reactive Webflux properties start with spring.webflux. Maybe that helps.

Comment: Try to set this instead `spring.codec.max-in-memory-size = 500kb` and see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this works:

```
package me.janam.api

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.http.codec.ServerCodecConfigurer
import org.springframework.web.reactive.config.EnableWebFlux
import org.springframework.web.reactive.config.WebFluxConfigurer

@Configuration
@EnableWebFlux
class WebConfig : WebFluxConfigurer {
    override fun configureHttpMessageCodecs(configurer: ServerCodecConfigurer) {
        configurer.defaultCodecs().maxInMemorySize(-1)
    }
}
```